# Auto load CSS code, when site is open

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

this is HTML code:

```
<div class="box">
    <a class="button" href="#popup1">Let me Pop up</a>
</div>

<div id="popup1" class="overlay">
    <div class="popup">
        <h2>Here i am</h2>
        <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
        <div class="content">
            Thank to pop me out of that button, but now i'm done so you can close this window.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want when open the page, box(popup) auto load and delete button.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Stack overflow isn't here to write code for you, however most people will be happy to help if you research the problem and show us where you're going wrong. I recommend having a look at the guide to asking a good question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

You need to learn jQuery for these things.
Have a look that this Document.
https://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Answer (score 1):

here is popup:

```js
jQuery(window).load(function(){
jQuery('#popup1').fadeIn();

});
jQuery('.close').click(function(){

jQuery('#popup1').fadeOut();

});
```

```css
#popup1{position:fixed;left:0;top:0;background:rgba(0,0,0,.5);z-index:1;width: 100%;
    height: 100%;display:none}
.popup{position:fixed;width:200px;height:200px;left:0;right:0;top:0;bottom:0;margin:auto;background:#000;z-index:2;color:#fff}
.close{position:absolute;top:0;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
    <a class="button" href="#popup1">Let me Pop up</a>
</div>

<div id="popup1" class="overlay">
    <div class="popup">
        <h2>Here i am</h2>
        <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
        <div class="content">
            Thank to pop me out of that button, but now i'm done so you can close this window.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```